# RAILS Add trigger into a migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, triggers, migration

I use mysql in a rails app and i want to create a trigger, but with a migration.
This is my sql code

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER check_validation_participant
BEFORE UPDATE ON participants
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE valide INTEGER;


IF NEW.current_state = 1 THEN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO valide
    FROM participants
    WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
    AND current_state = 1;


    IF valide > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Un événement est déjà validé pour cet utilisateur';
    END IF;
END IF;
END;;
```

In migration i write this code into execute "..." but i have a lot of syntax errors.
Thank you :)

Comment: Please explain what are the errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay you just have to do

```
execute <<-SQL

CREATE TRIGGER check_validation_participant
BEFORE UPDATE ON participants
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  DECLARE valide INTEGER;

  IF NEW.current_state = 1 THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO valide
    FROM participants
    WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
    AND current_state = 1;

    IF valide > 0 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Un événement est déjà validé pour cet utilisateur';
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;

SQL
```

It is because rails can execute instruction "DELIMITER" because it's a mysql syntax.